# Calling function in views.py from template using jaavascrpt

Tags: javascript, django

Is it possible to call a function in views.py from a template without having url?

I have two droplists on for authors and the other one for the books.
When someone selects an author I need to call a function in views.py to got books that related to the author so the second droplist should include books that belong to the author.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for an AJAX call from the template. Take a look at [this article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html)

Comment: This is nice work, but I am looking for a way do that without url or creating another HTML file.

Comment: In order to make a call to the server you need a URL. You could use websockets but they will also require another type of URL. I don't think calling a server side function from javascript like you want is possible.

Comment: without AJAX means you may need to store a json of relations and call javascript to parse it accordingly